# What does it mean to have "Web browser is waiting for data from the server" high on a speed test site. I have 21560.1s in wait time?

Tags: performance, page-speed, load-time, google-pagespeed

The web page took 22792 ms to load, used 119 requests, and weighed in at 1.7 MB.

The Google Page Speed performance grade for this web page is 70/100.

I'm looking to decrease my load times, but am unsure of what further I can do. I believe my images are as low as I can get them without compromising any more quality.

[image: These are my results]

Any help is appreciated.

TIA

Comment: That's close to 6 hours wait time, isn't it? I would think there is an error in your code that's preventing the page/script from finishing/exiting.

Comment: Any idea of how I could identify what that issue would be? Running off Wordpress and have CloudFront installed but in the last 4 weeks have had severe loading time issues and random 504 errors that last for a couple of minutes. Appreciate the help!

Comment: We can really only make guesses...see the linked question for some ideas. Since you're getting `504` errors, it's likely due to your server or network being overloaded.  Unless you have a WordPress cache plugin setup, a CDN isn't gong to help much. Dynamic content isn't typically cached by CDNs, so requests come directly from your server. I'd suggest testing a simple HTML file and comparing that with your WordPress URLs - if it's much faster, then your server is getting bogged down by WordPress and plugins. I'd suggest talking with your hosting provider to upgrade in that case.